# How can I deploy a simple Tkinter python program?

Tags: python, tkinter, deployment

this is my first question on the holy boards of stack overflow.

I am a hobby programmer and am therefore missing deep technical know-how. Nevertheless, I created a simple **python** application for my girlfriend to check, track and visualize her expenses (manual input). I created a `.csv` file that gets read into a pandas dataframe, connected with the user inputs available by `tkinter` and visualize it with matplotlib.
The whole program is in one `.py` file, I will list my imports down below and we both use **MacBooks**.

My questions are:

1. Are my imports "good" or "right" as they are? Or should I, e.g., only import the classes and functions that I need for the code to work?
2. How do I create an `.app` file that only needs to be clicked (by my gf)? I found py2app and fbs and executed some terminal code but it didnt work, I did not get my app. Also I am not sure (but this might be secondary) what the differences between deploying, freezing and packaging are.

Thank you very much in advance!

Best, Vic

```py
from tkinter import * 
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from dateutil.parser import parse
import os.path
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
```

Comment: Check out the [PEP8 - Python style-guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) for how to structure imports (in general: no unnecessary ones, no wildcards (*)). 
Making an executable can be done like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1164706/how-do-i-make-a-python-file-executable-on-macos-sierra/1164713).

Comment: great, this worked. Thank you! What would be the way of creating a standalone application without the terminal?

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853038/run-a-python-script-and-a-compiled-c-code-without-terminal-or-dock-item-in-mac-o) and possibly the related questions on the right.